# Housekeeping and tipping

Tags: usa

I'm staying at a motel for 3 months. I usually leave the do not disturb sign out. Once or twice a week I exchange towels. I clean the room myself. My question is, should I tip for the towels, even though it is a motel accommodation?

Comment: Remember tipping is always optional. It's entirely up to you whether you tip.

Comment: Although it is entirely up to you, you are already depriving the cleaners of the money they would have got for cleaning your room. I would tip generously for any services you do use.

Comment: You're "depriving the cleaners of the money they would have got for cleaning your room", so that means you should pay them more for the few services you *do* use? I'll never understand America.

Comment: @Omegastick: is not about America, and it seems you have a very capitalistic view. You have the cleaning service: they must be ready for you. This is a service. You got a clean room at beginning, and the cleaning people should work harder to clean when you will go.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, and I pay for this service when I rent the room. I don't see why I should pay more for *not* using the service.

Comment: @Omegastick As I said, it is entirely up to the potential tipper. I have a lot of sympathy with hotel cleaning staff, so I do have my room cleaned but try to make sure it is tidy so it will be easy to do. Others may not care about cleaners, in which case not having the room cleaned and not tipping are both fine.

Comment: @Omegastick Well, no. Patricia Shanahan's statement is not exactly correct. And housekeeping pay is not specific to the US as tipping not generally factored so your conclusion is without basis. Not all rooms are expected to be serviced every day so no one is being 'deprived' of income they would not make anyway.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It IS about America. America is tip obsessed. No other country would be having this conversation.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan By your logic, every time I make coffee for myself at home I should go to my local coffee shop and give them a tip, because i was depriving them of income when I didn't buy a coffee.

Comment: This all assumes that the cleaning staff isn't paid when all rooms have a DND sign out, correct?

Comment: Their paid an hourly wage.

Answer (score 2):

Many hotels now encourage guests to skip daily housekeeping so what you are doing is not unusual in any way.  And extended stay hotels usually offer only weekly service anyway unless you ask for it.

Weather you want to tip or not is up to you.  Some do, most don't and hotel housekeeping is generally not a tipped service job but tips are certainly welcome by the staff.

One last point, if you call for towels to be brought up, then a small tip would be appropriate but not necessarily expected or required.